# How to do e2e test in nestjs using mock data

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, nestjs, e2e-testing

I have an api in controller of nestjs.
First it checks wheter there is a center info or no.
After that, it makes a client.

```
  @Post('/client')
  public async createClient(
    @Body() createClientDto: CreateClientDto,
    @Req() req,
    @Res() res,
  ) {
    const { centerId } = createClientDto;

    let center = null;
    try {
      center = await this.centersReadService.findCenter(centerId);
    } catch (err) {
      throw new HttpException(
        {
          errorLog: err.message,
        },
        500,
      );
    }
    if (!center) {
      throw new HttpException(
        {
           popup: 'There is no center"
        },
        500,
      );
    }
    
    await this.clientCreateService.createClient(createClientDto)
    return res.json({})
  }
```

I made e2e test about this api.
It runs on 'docker-compose', so this app-test is running on localhost:20000.
I hope that it dosen't run new app with new port.
In this test, I want to get 'center=null' by findCenter method regardless of 'centerId' of 'createClientDto'.
Is is possible that some methods return fixed value using e2e test?

```
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { t_CreateClientDto } from './mock-data';

describe('Masters Clients Post (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  const testUrl = 'http://localhost:20000';

  it('can't create a client since there is no center.', () => {
    return request(testUrl)
      .post('/users/v1/masters/client')
      .send(t_CreateClientDto)
      .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.body.popup).toBe('There is no center');
      })
      .expect(500);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why not cypress?

Comment: How do you start your test? If you run docker compose separately then you should be able to verify that the API works and if it does then there might be something up with your testing. If that's the case, please update your question so that someone is more able to help you.